# Problems with connection to MongoLab from shell

Tags: mongodb, shell, mlab

I try to connect to my remote DB on MongoLab.
I use standard connection string:

```
mongo dsXXXXXX.mongolab.com:XXXXX/iet -u dbuser -p dbpassword
```

But when I try to connect I see such messages in shell:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.8
connecting to: dsXXXXXX.mongolab.com:XXXXX/iet
rs-dsXXXXXX:PRIMARY>
```

What does `PRIMARY` mean?

Answer (score 2):

It means that you are connected to the primary member of a mongo replica set.

Here is a link to the Mongo documentation about Mongo Replica Set Architectures
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-architectures/